# xPath: searching for uncompleted strings

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to search through an XML document with an uncompleted string.

```
<FB PointX="10" PointY="51" Name="LgtCmd$1_PreWarnAct">
```

As You see in that XML Line above there's an attribute named "Name".
My search term for example is: "LgtCmd"

So if I search with this xPath expression:

```
.//FB[@Name="LgtCmd"]/@Typ'
```

I get no results.

So my question:
How do I have to search to find that XML Node?

Answer (score 1):

XPath 1.0 defines two functions you might use: `contains` and `starts-with`.

```
.//FB[starts-with(@Name, "LgtCmd")]/@Typ
```